# Рандомно TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "Каждый раз разный ключ")

Tags: reactjs

Существует ситуация

```
axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${activeCity}&appid=${API_KEY}&lang=ru&units=metric`)
    .then(responce => {
      setCurrentWeather(responce.data);
      console.warn(responce.data);
    }).catch(err => alert(err));
```

тут мы получаем данные с сервера и кладем в стейт `currentWeather`. Далее я передаю эту информацию в дочерние компоненты и внезапно получаю `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "Каждый раз разный ключ")`. (На примере ниже получается `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')`). Хотя это не первое обращение к `currentWeather` в компоненте

```
 <div className="clouds">Облачность:</div>
       <p>{currentWeather.weather && `${currentWeather.clouds.all}%`}</p>
       </div>
 >    <div className={styles.progressClouds}><div style={{width: `${currentWeather.clouds.all}%`}}></div></div>
         {/* === Видимость ===*/}
          <div className={styles.visibilityContainer}>
```

Судя по тому, что мы не падаем в catch - запрос выполняется успешно и данные получены. Тем более что код работал. Следовательно непонятно почему вдруг стейт стал `undefined` и почему ошибка выбрасывается каждый раз на разный ключ у объекта`currentWeather`. То один не может прочитать, то другой.

Работали проверки по типу

```
<p>{currentWeather.clouds.all && `${currentWeather.clouds.all}%`}</p>
```

это решало проблему и приложение не падало.

Возможно, проблема с асинхронностью. Может ли быть такое, что компонент пытается читать данные из стейта раньше, чем они там появляются?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <p>{currentWeather.weather && `${currentWeather.clouds.all}%`}</p>
> ```

Ну так надо проверять то поле, из которого делается чтение, а не другое:

```
<p>{currentWeather.clouds && `${currentWeather.clouds.all}%`}</p>
```

Comment: Допустил неточность в вопросе. Ситуация ```<p>{currentWeather.clouds.all && `${currentWeather.clouds.all}%`}</p>``` решает (?) проблему, по крайней мере приложение не падает. Получается так необходимо сделать для каждой ситуации чтения из currentWeather?

Comment: @Vitaliy, не решает, конечно. Может уже подумаешь?

Comment: ♦, очевидно что запрос на получение данных срабатывает успешно, иначе был бы alert с ошибкой. Следовательно что-то (не undefined) должно падать в currentWeather. Однако компонент может читать стейт в еще не обновленном состоянии (без данных сервера, а изначально стейт инициализируется пустым объектом) и тогда получается мы пытаемся читать поля пустого объекта (их не существует). Мои мысли идут в этом направлении.

Comment: @Vitaliy, у тебя `clouds` undefined.

Comment: Маловероятно, так как ```<p className={styles.currentTemp}>{currentWeather.main.temp && `${currentWeather.main.temp}\u00B0C`}</p>``` выдает **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')**. Такое ощущение что currentWeather реально пустой объект, у которого вообще нет полей.

Comment: @Vitaliy, а тут `main` undefined. Может и пустой.

Comment: Да, объект был полностью пустым. Инициализирую заглушкой, имитирующей реальные данные. По крайней мере проект теперь не ломается. Что с этим делать - пока не знаю.